# Send jQuery Sortable With Ajax & MYSQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have found this http://linssen.me/entry/extending-the-jquery-sortable-with-ajax-mysql/

But I'm trying to send the data with "POST" :
What did I do wrong ?

```
function submitData ()
{
  $.ajax({
          url: './post_occupation_data',
          type: 'POST'
          data: {'data': $('#sortable2').sortable('serialize')}
         });

}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? Please try being more specific.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on the data line

Comment: You are missing a comma on the `type: 'POST'` line

Comment: Feeling stupid, thank you guys !